# Sum of Columns of Two Tables in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have two related tables in MS SQL.

```
Example...
Table A – Room
RoomId
RoomCost

Table B – RoomItem
RoomItemId
ItemName
ItemCost
RoomId
```

I need help in writing a LINQ code that will add RoomCost then Sum ItemCost (if they have the same RoomId) and post the results in a WPF textbox.
So far I have tried

```
DataclassesDataContext dc= new DataclassesDataContext();
var RoomAmount = (from dbo in dc.Room select dbo.RoomCost).Single();
var ItemAmount = (from itm in dc.RoomItem select itm.ItemCost).Single();
decimal RmAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(RoomAmount);
decimal ItmAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(ItemAmount);
decimal TAmount=RmAmount+ItmAmout;
txtTotalAmount.Text=TAmount
```

I am a beginner in C#, Kindly help. If I haven't been clear enough, just ask. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post rather than adding comments, and format it appropriately. If you click on "edit" there's a question mark in the top right corner which will help you to present your question in a readable way.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Sum() like (havent tested it):

Assuming that *Room.RoomCost* is **decimal** and *RoomItem.ItemCost* is **decimal** as well and **myRoomId** is the id of the room you want to sum up:

```
var roomAmount = dc.Room.Single(r => r.RoomId == myRoomId).RoomCost;
var itemAmount = dc.RoomItem.Where(i => i.RoomId == myRoomId).Sum(r => r.ItemCost);

txtTotalAmount.Text= roomAmount + itemAmount ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming correct associations on the room and room items.

```
var foo = from room in dc.Room
          select new { room , TotalCost = room.RoomCost + room.RoomItems.Sum(item => item.ItemCost) };
var bar = foo.Single(room => room.RoomId == myRoomId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do this by linq inner join and group by 
see example here : [LINQ: Using INNER JOIN, Group and SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530925/linq-using-inner-join-group-and-sum) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count)
and to add two column see example http://forums.asp.net/t/1728644.aspx/1

so from this links your query like

```
var total = from room in dc.Room
        join item in dc.RoomItem on room.RoomID equals item.RoomID
        group item by room.RoomID into g
        select new { 
            RoomID = room.RoomID, 
            RoomCost = (room.RoomCost + g.Sum(t => t.ItemCost))
        };
```