# How to do inner join, group by and count using linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is the output of joining 2 tables by inner join.

[image]

I want linq query of joing two table as inner join and group by name from one table and sum of total from another table column as taken snapshot as above.pls help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: Using INNER JOIN, Group and SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530925/linq-using-inner-join-group-and-sum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530925/linq-using-inner-join-group-and-sum)

```
var result = (from a in ctx.TableA
             join b in ctx.TableB on a.Id equals b.Id
             group a by a.Name into g
             select new
             {
                Name = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(i => i.Total)
             }).ToList();
```