# Convert SQL to Linq, adding multiple column values

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I am doing my university project, I don't have much experience in using linq, I have a SQL statement and need some help converting it to linq. Please help

```
SELECT 
    r.Id AS emp,
    a.LeaveTypeID AS leave, 
    t.LeaveType,
    SUM(NumDaysRequested) AS TotalDays,
    SUM(NumHoursRequested) AS TotalHours,
    SUM(NumMinsRequested) AS TotalMins
FROM 
    tbl_LeaveRequested AS r 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_LeaveAllocation AS a ON r.LeaveTypeID = a.LeaveTypeID
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_LeaveType AS t ON t.LeaveTypeID = a.LeaveTypeID
WHERE
    LeaveStatus != 'Rejected'
GROUP BY
    r.Id, a.LeaveTypeID, t.LeaveType
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ: Using INNER JOIN, Group and SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530925/). That was just one of many similar examples that can be found with a search for "[\[linq\] join group sum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinq%5D+join+group+sum)". Adapting the answers to calculate multiple sums should be pretty straight-forward. Finally, although we do not post ChatGPT answers here, you can try asking ChatGPT to "convert the following SQL to LINQ: ..." and get a pretty good answer. You can also ask it to "convert to linq methods"..

Comment: If after trying the above, you are still having problems, add your attempt to the post and we can assist further.

Comment: One bump in the learning curve is understanding the result of `group by` and `.GroupBy()` in linq. In it's simplest form, `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TSource>>` result. This is an enumerable collection of groups, where each group has both a key (which may be a compound anonymous type) and a collection of group members. From there, you can map the results using a `.Select()` where (for each group) you extract a combination of group key values and aggregations of the members of each group.

Comment: *Slight correction: The reference to `IEnumerable` above should have been `IQueryable`.*

Comment: SQL queries can't be converted into LINQ. They can be emulated, but that requires knowledge of the class model. Also the exact Entity Framework version is relevant (please choose the appropriate tag, ef-core-XX).